# These credentials do not match our records. laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

i got some error when tying to login use user that i make from seeder, i try to add this in my User.php

```
    public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
{
    $this->attributes['password'] = \Hash::make($password);
}
```

and here is my seeder

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\User;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        User::create([
            'name' => Str::random(10),
            'email' => Str::random(10).'@gmail.com',
            'password' => bcrypt('12345678'),
        ]);
    }
}
```

anyone know where causes error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are hashing the password twice. You have a mutator that is hashing the password for you and you are assigning a hash to that attribute so it is hashing twice.  (`bcrypt` then `Hash::make`, 2 rounds of hashing)

Just use the mutator to do the hashing and pass the plain text version of the password as the attributes value.

Comment: then what should i do? change ['password'] to bcrypt?

Comment: decide whether you want to use a mutator (which means you would have to assign the plain text form of the password to the attribute, so the mutator can then hash it) or don't use a mutator and everywhere you save a password you have to hash it ... currently you would just have to assign the plain text password in your seeder and the mutator will hash it for you, just don't call `bcrypt` in the seeder :-)